# What is a term for a person who defends another person or their actions no matter what?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some examples:

- Someone defending their friend even if they know what the friend did was wrong.
- Defense lawyers who know their client is guilty but fight to prove otherwise
- Someone who sacrifices themselves to protect one or more others even at the cost of their lives

The 3rd example as a verb is basically the definition of heroic sacrifice, but what is the agent called? Is it simply a hero? While that definitely applies to those who die saving others, I don't feel like that term can be applied nearly as generously to the other examples. Is there perhaps a form of altruism that describes this?

Comment: loyal to the death?

Comment: Welcome to English SE. Could you add a little more detail to your question, e.g. by specifying an example sentence where you might want to use this word?

Answer (score 1):

This answer wont do, but it's close. According to The Random House College dictionary a **myrmidon** is "a person who executes without scruples his master's commands. The poster does not insist on someone's serving a master, but he does ask for the idea of blindly defending someone in the wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider ***apologist*** as in David Irving, the British revisionist "historian" and apologist for Hitler's Third Reich, who was branded a liar, Holocaust denier and falsifier of history by the presiding judge in his (Irving) failed High Court libel action against Professor Lipstadt and Penguin Books.

**Apologist:** A person who offers an argument in defence of something controversial. (Oxford Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

> #### Sophistry
>
> **noun**
>
> - the use of clever but false arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving.
>     *"trying to argue that I had benefited in any way from the disaster was pure sophistry"*
> - a fallacious argument.
>     "*he went along with this sophistry, but his heart clearly wasn't in it"*

Answer (score 0):

How about ***advocate***?

OD:

[***advocate***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/advocate): a person who puts a case on someone else's behalf

One can be an ***advocate*** for another even if one knows that the other is or may be in the wrong, as in your example of the defense lawyer.

Another possibility is the idiom ***have (got) someone's back***.

OD:

> [***have (got) someone's
>   back***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have_(got)_someone's_back):
>   Be prepared to offer support or assistance to someone: *‘my parents
>   always have my back’*
>
> More example sentences
>
> ‘I can trust that my wife will have my back.’
>
> ‘What she needs is to know that you've got her back if things get
>   rough for her, that you're looking out for her best interest.’
>
> ‘I'm his friend and I've got his back.’

In many contexts, ***having someone's back*** means being behind them *no matter what*.

Answer (score 0):

I would call such a person (a) [*partisan*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/partisan) (the word can be both a noun and an adjective). From Merriam-Webster:

> a firm adherent to a party, faction, cause, or person; *especially* : 
>   one exhibiting blind, prejudiced, and unreasoning allegiance

This term comes up a lot in discussions of politics (*partisan politics* is basically "my party, right or wrong"), but can refer to someone with an unreasoning allegiance to individuals as well as causes or political parties. For example:

> Who could he talk to? . . . He thought of Rebecca and at once knew it
>   was impossible. She was too **partisan**, too hostile. —[Lillian Darcy, *A Nurse in Crisis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lc8iDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT64&dq=%22too%20partisan%22%20-politics%20-congress%20friend%20love&pg=PT64#v=onepage&q=%22too%20partisan%22%20-politics%20-congress%20friend%20love&f=false)
>
> [T]he book lacks definiteness and, more seriously, is marked by a
>   sympathy that too frequently becomes outright **partisan** defense.
>   —[Book Review Digest, Volume 62, snippet view](https://books.google.com/books?id=QjwOAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22partisan%20defense%22%20-politics%20-congress%20friend%20love&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22partisan%20defense%22)

Since you mention a word that would apply to an attorney, here's one more example:

> This process does not assure that the adversarial system will be at
>   play on appeal, because the appellate court will not be looking at the
>   record with an adversary's eye for finding plausible claims, as is
>   expected of a **partisan** defense lawyer. —[Joshua Dressler & Alan C.
>   Michaels. *Understanding Criminal Procedure*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RQPLeofcl14C&lpg=PT798&dq=%22partisan%20defense%22%20attorney%20-%22partisan%20defense%20committee%22&pg=PT798#v=onepage&q=%22partisan%20defense%22%20attorney%20-%22partisan%20defense%20committee%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but you can consider ***unquestioning defender***.

[**Unquestioning:**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unquestioning)

> Unquestioning obedience is total, and given without thinking, asking questions, or doubting. (Cambridge Dictionary)

And I would use the word as follows:

> I don't want to be an unquestioning defender.